# Cannot parse JSONArray using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have encountered a problem whilst developing my Android application.  My problem is that I don't know how to parse JSON code from an URL using GSON.  I searched Google and SO for about an hour or so, but nothing worked for me.  Everything I found on the internet referred to custom JSON code, not code from an URL.  Here is a small sample of the data I have.

```
  {
    "status": {
        "error": "NO",
        "code": 200,
        "description": "none",
        "message": "Request ok"
    },
    "geoLocation": {
        "city_id": "147",
        "city_long": "Saint-Laurent",
        "region_short": "QC",
        "region_long": "Quebec",
        "country_long": "Canada",
        "country_id": "43",
        "region_id": "35"
    },
    "stations": [
        {
            "country": "Canada",
            "price": "3.65",
            "address": "3885, Boulevard Saint-Rose",
            "diesel": "0",
            "id": "33862",
            "lat": "45.492367",
            "lng": "-73.710915",
            "station": "Shell",
            "region": "Quebec",
            "city": "Saint-Laurent",
            "date": "3 hours agp",
            "distance": "1.9km"
        },
        {
            "country": "Canada",
            "price": "3.67",
            "address": "3885, Saint-Mary",
            "diesel": "0",
            "id": "33872",
            "lat": "45.492907",
            "lng": "-73.740715",
            "station": "Shell",
            "region": "Quebec",
            "city": "Saint-Laurent",
            "date": "3 hours agp",
            "distance": "2.0km"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am a beginner at JSON/GSON so I need a bit of help.  Here is what I have:

```
try {
            String sURL = "http://api.mygasfeed.com/stations/radius/(39.631439)/(-80.8005451)/(25)/reg/(price)/uc82wk25m0.json?callback=?";
            URL url = new URL(sURL);
            HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            request.connect();

            // Convert to a JSON object to print data
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
            JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
            JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //may be an array, may be an object.
            longitude = rootobj.get("price").getAsString();
            latitude = rootobj.get("address").getAsString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried a loop to parse the array but that failed miserably.  Any help regarding this problem is highly appreciated.

**------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------**
I am extremely sorry about the incorrrect JSON code.  I have updated the code but still cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: your json is incorrect. Check: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: How did it fail? If you have a stacktrace, please add it to your question.

Comment: use some online json validator

Comment: json not valid please check properly...error Parse error on line 1:
({    "status": { 
^
Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score 1):

You JSON is wrong:

```
   "date": "3 hours agp",
    "distance": "1.9km"
}
{
    "country": "Canada",
```

To coorect it, you must add a `,`

```
  "date": "3 hours agp",
    "distance": "1.9km"
},
{
    "country": "Canada",
```

Comment: Sorry, this was just a copying error.  The problem still persists.  If you want, please use the link in the code that I made.

Comment: @user3744439 If I open the file ther is an `?(` ? What should that be?

Comment: Hmmm... that is quite interesting.  I haven't seen this before.  Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: @user3744439 Store the response in a `string`, cut the values and parse the rest.

Comment: @user3744439 Remove "callback=?" from your url, that will remove "?(" from your response then it will work perfectly fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the basic **org.json.JSONObject** and **org.json.JSONArray** it works fine for me...

```
// This string is the JSON you gave as imput
String json = "{ \"status\": {  \"error\": \"NO\",  \"code\": 200,  \"description\": \"none\",  \"message\": \"Request ok\" }, \"geoLocation\": {  \"city_id\": \"147\",  \"city_long\": \"Saint-Laurent\",  \"region_short\": \"QC\",  \"region_long\": \"Quebec\",  \"country_long\": \"Canada\",  \"country_id\": \"43\",  \"region_id\": \"35\" }, \"stations\": [  {\"country\": \"Canada\",\"price\": \"3.65\",\"address\": \"3885, Boulevard Saint-Rose\",\"diesel\": \"0\",\"id\": \"33862\",\"lat\": \"45.492367\",\"lng\": \"-73.710915\",\"station\": \"Shell\",\"region\": \"Quebec\",\"city\": \"Saint-Laurent\",\"date\": \"3 hours agp\",\"distance\": \"1.9km\"  },  {\"country\": \"Canada\",\"price\": \"3.67\",\"address\": \"3885, Saint-Mary\",\"diesel\": \"0\",\"id\": \"33872\",\"lat\": \"45.492907\",\"lng\": \"-73.740715\",\"station\": \"Shell\",\"region\": \"Quebec\",\"city\": \"Saint-Laurent\",\"date\": \"3 hours agp\",\"distance\": \"2.0km\"  } ]}";

try{
    JSONObject rootobj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray array = rootobj.getJSONArray("stations");
    for( int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String price = o.getString("price");
        String address = o.getString("address");
        //...

    }
}catch(JSONException jse){
    // Manage Exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to fetch data from url and parse the response using Gson.

Note : Remove "?callback=?" from your url, that will remove "?(" from your response

```
try {
    String sURL = "http://api.mygasfeed.com/stations/radius/(39.631439)/(-80.8005451)/(25)/reg/(price)/uc82wk25m0.json";

    URL u = new URL(sURL);
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    request.setRequestMethod("GET");
    request.connect();
    int status = request.getResponseCode();

    switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));

            JsonElement element = new Gson().fromJson (br, JsonElement.class);
            JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();

            JsonArray jArray = jsonObj.get("stations").getAsJsonArray();

            for (int i = 0, size = jArray.length(); i < size; i++) {

               JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               System.out.println(" Price : " + jObj.get("price").toString());
               System.out.println(" Address : " + jObj.get("address").toString());
            }
    }

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    // Manage Exception here
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // Manage Exception here
}
```